# Google admob или реклама в приложениях android

Tags: android, admob

Делаю приложение. Стал вопрос монетизации. Приложение создано  под android юзеров из разных стран. Как происходить процес рекламы ? То есть реклама подвязана под конкретный регион и нужно просто добавить firebase ? И, кстати, посоветуйте, какой лучше вариант рекламы и стоит ли использовать admob или есть что-то получше ?  Приложение не игрового типа.

Comment: admob, vungle, mopub, adcolony хорошие. При подключении вопрос со странами решает сам нетворк и отдает рекламу под страну сам обычно. Вам просто подключить.